# Can I find sites in Google based on their source code?

Tags: search

I'm trying to find sites that use a certain WordPress template. Is it possible to find all sites that have a specific line in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a very difficult task to perform within Google, as powerful a search engine it may be. Luckily, there are specialized search engines to assist you with your task. I recommend giving https://meanpath.com/ a shot.

Cheers.